# Three.js: How to rotate a Sphere on Axis using camera rotation values

Tags: three.js, rotation

I have a special `control` called `SphericalControls`. Its similar to `OrbitControls`, but it keeps camera at position `0,0,0` and instead rotates camera on x and y to look around a scene. It is placed in the middle of a `SphereBufferGeometry` which has a 360 equirectangular image projected upon it. The user can look around the 360 image, and as he does the camera x and y rotation values change.

When a user clicks a button, I need to take these x and y rotation values and rotate the sphere to the rotation of the camera. I then set camera back to x:0 and y:0.

The result is that the camera is reset and the 360 scene has now rotated to show the same rotation view that the camera was previously looking at. So to the user, the view stays basically static, just the values for `camera.rotation` and sphere rotation have swapped.

This works great if I offset the texture on the sphere:

```
sphereObj.material.map.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
sphereObj.material.map.offset.x = ((camera.rotation.x) / (Math.PI * 2));
sphereObj.material.map.needsUpdate = true;
sphereObj.material.needsUpdate = true;

camera.rotation.set(0, 0);
// Success!
```

But what I need to do is not offset the texture, but rotate the entire geometry. I have tried:

```
var axis = new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0).normalize();;
var offsetRadian = ((camera.rotation.x) / (Math.PI * 2));
sphere.rotateOnAxis(axis, offsetRadian);
// Fail
```

But the result is that the sphere rotation is off by approx 30%. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Every objects' rotational data is stored in their [respective `.quaternion` object](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.quaternion). Both `camera` and `sphereObj` have a quaternion, so what you could do is copy the camera's rotational data into the sphere:

```js
// Get camera's rotation
targetRotation = camera.quaternion;

// Invert rotation
targetRotation.inverse();

// Set sphere's rotation
sphereObj.quaternion.copy(targetRotation);
camera.rotation.set(0, 0, 0);
```

I'm not entirely sure if you need the [`.inverse()`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Quaternion.inverse) line... if you're noticing the sphere is rotating in the opposite direction, just get rid of it to get the desired result.